# Bezier Point Radius - Set Multiple by Absolute vs Mean Value

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm a bit of a noob to blender, but for Bezier curve point radii, how can I assign a specific value to all selected points, vs the unintuitive "Mean Radius"? E.g., I don't want to preserve the proportions - I just want all points to have a radius of 1.

[image: Mean Radius Control]

[image: Ugly radius variation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control curve radius proportionally with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or the Curve Shrink Flatten operator as you already know. This will proportionally scale all vertex.

So set an absolute value for all selected vertex use the operator *Set Curve Radius* either from the tool shelf, or the space bar search menu, and enter the desired value.

[image]